# How to make a point move along a vector?

Tags: javascript, vector, openlayers, point

I have a vector loaded from an osm file, which is a polyline representing a tramway line and added this way :

```
var line = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Tramway : line 1", {
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: "lines/line1.osm",
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.OSM()
    }),
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    style: { strokeWidth: 5, strokeColor: "blue", strokeOpacity: 0.4, pointRadius: 6, fillOpacity: 0.4 }
});
```

I would want to have a point (which would represent a tramway) moving along this vector. I have to admit I didn't attempt to do anything since this doesn't look like anything I ever did with Openlayers and I have no idea how I can do this.

Is there a simple way to do this or do I have to do it manually ? I'm just looking for a little hint because I didn't find anything on the Internet about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A approach would be to step to the nodes of your line and use the xy-position for your tramway position:

```
//feature is the feature of line1
var a = [];
a = feature.geometry.getVertices();
for (var i=0; i<=a.length; i++) {  
    console.log("x: " + a[i].x + ",y: " + a[i].y);
}
```